# Why is my AutoComplete suggestion dropdown blank

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I have a Xamarin form where I am trying to add a SyncFusion AutoComplete control. The data is a simple class with only three string fields (CUSTNMBR, CUSTNAME, ZIP). I want it to match on any of the fields and display the coresponding `CUSTNMBR`. Here it my line in Xaml:

```xml
 <xForms:SfAutoComplete x:Name="customerAutoComplete" WidthRequest="120" BackgroundColor="White" />
```

In the form's code-behind constructor I call `LoadCustomerData()`:

```
private async void LoadCustomerData()
{
    customerAutoComplete.DataSource = await GetCustomerCodes();
    customerAutoComplete.DisplayMemberPath = "CUSTNMBR";
    customerAutoComplete.SelectedValuePath = "CUSTNMBR";
    customerAutoComplete.SuggestionMode = SuggestionMode.Custom;
    customerAutoComplete.Filter = FilterCustomers;
    customerAutoComplete.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
    customerAutoComplete.Watermark = "Zip Code, Customer ID, or Customer Name";
    customerAutoComplete.MinimumPrefixCharacters = 3;
}
```

Here is my filter method.

```
private bool FilterCustomers(string search, object customer)
{
    var text = customerAutoComplete.Text;

    if (customer != null)
    {
        var myCustomer = (OrganizationSearchDto)customer;
        if (myCustomer.CustName.Contains(text) || myCustomer.CustNmbr.Contains(text) ||
            myCustomer.Zip.Contains(text))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

The above code worked partially when I had `customerAutoComplete.SuggestionMode = SuggestionMode.Contains` but it did not match on the other two fields. Now it still runs, however nothing is shown in the dropdown list (its blank). Why is my dropdown blank? Any hints, suggestion or a hard shove in the right direction will be appreciated.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on `return true`, is that line reached for the customer(s) that you expect it to show? Kudos for confirming (and stating in the question) that it partially works when using SuggestionMode.Contains - that was a good first step to figuring out what is wrong. I'm not seeing anything obviously wrong (though I haven't used syncfusion).

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Yes, it hits the breakpoint.

Comment: I don't like calling an async method from a constructor (which isn't an async environment). I don't think that's an issue here (because the `Contains` version functioned ok), but is `GetCustomerCodes` calling out to a server? If so, have you done a test with hardcoded data, so that it can immediately return?

Comment: ANOTHER TEST: Swap `return true` and `return false`, so it is true for all the OTHER customers - the opposite of what you want. See if it is still blank. That would change where we need to look for a problem. ALSO: wrap the whole thing in a try-catch, and set a breakpoint in the catch block (maybe put `return false;` there). In case something is going wrong on one of the items.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Thanks, you helped me find the error. 1.) Properties names on `DisplayMemberPath` is case sensitive. 2.) My filter checks are case sensitive as well. You led me through the steps that led me to the answer, so please make an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone encountering this, tests to try:

1. Put a breakpoint on `return true` - is that breakpoint hit for the customer(s) you expect to be shown as suggestions?
2. Swap return true and return false, so it is true for all the OTHER customers - the opposite of what you want. See if it is still blank. If it is, then it isn't the filter - code elsewhere is interfering with display. Would need to show more code, or make a github containing a minimum repo that shows the problem.
3. [from OP] The issue was that property names on `DisplayMemberPath` are case sensitive, as are the filter checks.

The fix for the filter was to ignore case everywhere. E.g.

```
if (myCustomer.CustName.ToLower().Contains(text.ToLower()) || ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

We have analyzed the reported query. We have achieved the requirement by using the following code snippet,

```
public bool ContainingSpaceFilter(string search, object item)
{
    if (item != null)
    {
        var myCustomer = item as Employee;

        if (**myCustomer.Name.ToUpper().Contains(search.ToUpper()**) || myCustomer.ID.Contains(search) ||
   myCustomer.ZipCode.Contains(search))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```